# TraMineR Using Weights

Tags: r, traminer, sequence-analysis

I am still new to `TraMineR`; therefore, my problem might be very simple for most of you.
I am working on some sequence plots with my data and would like to see the results with the survey weights and nominal weights. I am able to import data into R and run sequence plots with the data *as is*, but am unable to run it with weights.  I have included my syntax on how I created the state sequence objects (pretty naïve) and a two sequence plot examples. How do I write syntax to use weights? Thanks

**Data file:** `DISDATAC`; **Survey weights:** `WTSURVY`; **Nominal weights:** `NORMWEIGHTS`

```
DISDATAC<-read.spss("/Users/tac0432/Desktop/DISDATAC.sav",to.data.frame=TRUE,use.value.labels=TRUE,)
DISDATAC.shortlab <- c("2yr", "4yr", "Gov","Bus","UeL")
DISDATAC.lab <- c("2year college or Other School System", " 4year college or Medical Institution", " Government","Business/Industry","Unemployed or Not in the labor force")
DISDATAC.seq <- seqdef(DISDATAC, 09:12, states = DISDATAC.shortlab, labels = DISDATAC.lab)
DISDATAC.seq[1:20, 1:4] ; print(DISDATAC.seq[1:20, ], format = "SPS"); alphabet(DISDATAC.seq)
stlab(DISDATAC.seq)

Sequence Plot Syntax examples
seqIplot(DISDATAW.seq, border = NA, group = DISDATAW$NMRMEMG, sortv = "from.start")
seqIplot(DISDATAW.seq, border = NA, group = DISDATAW$GENDER:DISDATAW$NMRMEMG, sortv = "from.start")
```

Answer (score 3):

Hard to be certain without a sample of your data to play with, but it looks like you need to provide a column of `weights` in the `seqdef` function. If you do that, the `TraMineR` plotting functions account for the weights by default.

If you follow the help for `seqIplot`, you can get to the help page that discusses weights. Here's the key section from the help for `seqIplot`:

> If weights have been specified when creating `seqdata`, weighted
>   frequencies will be returned by `seqtab` since the default option is
>   `weighted=TRUE`. See examples below, the `seqtab` and `plot.stslist.freq`
>   manual pages for a complete list of optional arguments and Müller et
>   al., (2008) for a description of sequence frequency plots.

So we need to look at the function `seqdef`, which creates the `seqdata` object for plotting. The help for `seqdef` describes the `weights` argument:

> `weights`    optional numerical vector containing weights, which are
>   accounted for by plotting and statistical functions when applicable.

The help also has an example of how to specify the weights in `seqdef`.